# Is there a way to retrieve if a column is auto increment and signed/unsigned in pyodbc?

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I am trying to retrieve metadata from columns in a MySQL table using pyodbc.

I have looked at the cursor.columns, which contains more or less what I need, only it does not provide wether a column is auto increment or not. Also, it does not provide a field to show if a value is signed or unsigned.

I know it is possible to retrieve this from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table, but I would like to avoid creating queries for this table.

So, is there any good way to achieve this using pyodbc's built in functions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe `pyodbc` has this feature.  `pyodbc` does three basic things.  1) Connect to a database.  2) Send sql statements to a database.  3) Retrieve results of sql statments.   So while you don't want to write queries to inspect a table, it's really the right way to go.  (I'm sure someone will pipe up if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Thx for your quick answer! I was just thinking since a lot of metadata returned from cursor.columns is also in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table, there might be a way of using pyodbc. I'll leave it open for now to see if anyone else has something..

Comment: I posted this as a comment (not an answer) because what I said was conjecture.  I am not an authority on `pyodbc`.  Unfortunately, the `pyodbc` docs are a bit thin.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid creating queries? Behind the scenes, `cursor.columns()` is calling an [ODBC function (SQLColumns)](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#columns), which the driver translates into a DBMS platform-specific query to return column metadata. In the end, cursor.columns() is just abstracting query execution, so don't be concerned with creating queries.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I wanted to use the built in functions as much as possible, since I will be using the same code for different DB types in the future. If I write the queries I'll need to change them for every different DB type, which wouldn't be necessary if pyodbc already had this functionality.